# Get the count of activity based on relative delta from today

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like below, about a million rows with unique person_id

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
| person_id |    date    | activity |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| A         | 31/03/2022 | Sell     |
| A         | 02/03/2023 | Buy      |
| A         | 29/08/2023 | Buy      |
| A         | 13/05/2023 | Buy      |
| A         | 28/02/2023 | Sell     |
| A         | 02/01/2024 | Sell     |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I want to calculate count of activity based on time when the activity was created till "today" and group them based on the person_id. the new columns will be 12 months, 9 months, 6 months and 3 months for each buy and sell.

For example, if someone is to ask, how many "buy" did person A had in past 3 months (from "today") then we should be able to answer zero. and if asked the same about "sell" we should say one.

Here, the length is calculated from current date which is the system date on the day the script has run.

The output should look like below.

```
+-----------+------------+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| person_id |    date    | activity | buy_12m | buy_9m | buy_6m | buy_3m | sell_12m | sell_9m | sell_6m | sell_3m |
+-----------+------------+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| A         | 31/03/2022 | Sell     |       3 |      2 |      1 |      0 |        2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| A         | 02/03/2023 | Buy      |       3 |      2 |      1 |      0 |        2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| A         | 29/08/2023 | Buy      |       3 |      2 |      1 |      0 |        2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| A         | 13/05/2023 | Buy      |       3 |      2 |      1 |      0 |        2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| A         | 28/02/2023 | Sell     |       3 |      2 |      1 |      0 |        2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| A         | 02/01/2024 | Sell     |       3 |      2 |      1 |      0 |        2 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
+-----------+------------+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The count of input rows will be same as output, I am sort of "exploding" the group_by results to every row. I am fine with the duplication like this as this is connected to another system which expects same number of rows.

I did this my way but have been using relativedelta and a lot of joins and group_by, so ended up with very long code with takes time to execute.

Comment: I don't understand why you want an input equal to the output and not only one row per person because you compute the buy/sell from today.

Comment: I get your point and I delivererd the same saying that if we are grouping by, then there is no need to duplicate and cause unnecessary big file size. However, I was told that the data in this file feeds in to a system which expects same number of rows as per the extract, therefore I had to make this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import itertools
# +-----------+------------+----------+
# | person_id |    date    | activity |
# +-----------+------------+----------+
# | A         | 31/03/2022 | Sell     |
# | A         | 02/03/2023 | Buy      |
# | A         | 29/08/2023 | Buy      |
# | A         | 13/05/2023 | Buy      |
# | A         | 28/02/2023 | Sell     |
# | A         | 02/01/2024 | Sell     |
# +-----------+------------+----------+

data = {
    'person_id': ['A'] * 6,
    'date': ['2022-03-31', '2023-03-02', '2023-08-29', '2023-05-13', '2023-02-15', '2024-01-02'],
    'activity': ['Sell'] + ['Buy'] * 3 + ['Sell'] * 2
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['today'] = pd.to_datetime('2024-01-04')
df['nr_of_months_passed'] = (df.today.dt.to_period('M') - df.date.dt.to_period('M')).apply(lambda x: x.n)
df['nr_of_months_passed_r'] = np.round(df['nr_of_months_passed'] / 3, 0) * 3

def calc_cols(df):
    for action, month in itertools.product(['Buy', 'Sell'], [3,6,9,12]):        
        df[f'{action.lower()}_{month}m'] = ((df['nr_of_months_passed'] <= month) & (df['activity'] == action)).sum()
    return df

df.groupby('person_id').apply(calc_cols)
```

This returns:
[image]